# Iframe no se muestra en dispositivos android en navegador chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Verán, tengo la siguiente situación, tengo un Iframe que se muestra en dispositivos apple sin problema, no importa el modelo, en escritorio/pc se muestra sin problema, en dispositivos android con cualquier navegador que no sea chrome se muestra correctamente, ahora, con dispositivos android y navegador chrome algunas veces se muestra el IFrame y otras no, mi IFrame es el siguiente:

```
<iframe id="lgnIfra" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" onLoad="resize()" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="<%=path%>" align="bottom" iframe.src="javascript:parent.getFrameHTML()"></iframe>
```

Hay alguna forma de que cargue sin problema alguno el IFrame en dispositivos android y usando chrome como navegador?

Edit1

Lo que se me ocurre hacer es que haga otra cosa cuando ese id del iframe sea cargado y llame otra función, entonces intente lago cómo esto:

```
function resize() {
    var form = document.getElementById("lgnIfra");
    if(form != "lgnIfra"){
        $('iframe:not(.not_resize)').each(function(index, iframe){
            iframe.style.height = 0;
            iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        });
    }else{
        $('#lgnIfra').load(function(){
            var Height = document.getElementById('lgnIfra').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            document.getElementById('lgnIfra').height = Height + 40;
        });
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona, mi pregunta, estoy obteniendo de manera correcta el id del iframe?